# Android Studio Setup Wizard - Can't choose Virtual Device

Tags: react-native, android-studio

**Image of problem**: [Android Studio refuses Virtual Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSgQ8.png)

Android Virtual Device is installed with the Android Studio download and should say "Installed," but instead, it says "unavailable."

I'm returning from a three year code hiatus and was thinking of diving into React Native, but man did I just step into something odd that I must ask you about.

In the **Setup Wizard** for Android studio, it says the Android Virtual Device can't be clicked and says "unavailable."

1. I have tried re-downloading Android Studio both with downloading the virtual device and without, same problem.
2. I can't seem to find anything about it across the internet, rather the problems might be when it's up and running not in the Wizard.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Just tried installing Android Studio, ran into the same problem with the installation wizard.

Comment: From my googling I can't find any real information on it, it feels like Im missing something simple.

Comment: Have you ran into any problems running the studio thus far though? For me I seem to be having some issues with getting the licenses working for flutter, but other than that I haven't had any major problems. I tried creating a virtual device from the avd manager and it worked normally other than having to manually direct it to the abd file